# Where does Lambda store the retry count for a Kinesis batch?

Tags: go, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-go, amazon-kinesis

I have several Lambdas that are triggred by Kinesis. The Lambdas are configured to handle a [Kinesis Event struct](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/blob/main/events/kinesis.go#L5) - this event struct essentially contains a slice of Kinesis Records (so that one Lambda invocation can process thousands of records from a stream).

I've configured my Lambdas to enable `BisectBatchOnFunctionError` (documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html#streams-batchfailurereporting-bisect) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-failure-handling-features-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources/)) and `MaximumRetryAttempts` (to limit the number of retries if the Lambda errors out). I would like to keep track of the number of retries for Kinesis batches - since an increase in retries could be the result of either an API error or a malformed Kinesis record.

Since I'm able to specify the `MaximumRetryAttempts` for a batch, then it stands to reason that the number of retries has to be tracked for each batch too (otherwise AWS wouldn't be able to tell whether the `MaximumRetryAttempts` had been met/exceeded) - but I'm unable to find *where* this count is tracked.

I've looked at both the [aws-lambda-go](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/blob/main/events/kinesis.go) repo, and the [aws-sdk-go-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/main/service/kinesis/types/types.go) repo, and I can't find any reference to such a count. I've also looked through AWS docs, and can't find any reference to a retry count there either. Am I missing something here, or is this retry counter just some internal AWS metric?

Comment: This is most likely internal to the lamba service itself which is responsible for polling for events and triggering your lambda.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to keep track of the number of retries for Kinesis batches - since an increase in retries could be the result of either an API error or a malformed Kinesis record.

You can track this just by using the Lambda's `Errors` metric, which will emit a 1 if a retry happens since retries happen on Lambda errors. If you see a spike in the `Errors` metric then there is a spike in retries is happening as well.